# having issues with validation in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am building a travel agency program. I have been having trouble with setting a limit of people who can purchase a trip for example. The number I enter in the text field can only be positive and greater than 0 or a message "disabled" will be displayed as well as an error message. If the number is positive, the message will read "enabled" and I will be able to carry on. It's kind of a stupid question but I'm pretty new with javascript and I would appreciate the help. I will leave the code below.

```js
var enabled = false;

function validation(limit) {

  limit = parseInt($("#limit").val());

  if (!/\d/.test(limit)) {
    $("#enablemessage").show();
    $("#message").show();
    document.getElementById("message").style.color = "red";
    document.getElementById("enablemessage").innerHTML =
      "Disabled";
    document.getElementById("enablemessage").style.color = "red";
    $("#message").html("The value is not a number");
  } else if (limit == null || limit < 1) {
    $("#enablemessage").show();
    $("#message").show();
    document.getElementById("enablemessage").innerHTML =
      "Disabled";
    document.getElementById("enablemessage").style.color = "red";
    $("#message").html("The value must be greater than 1");
  } else if (limit >= 1) {
    enabled = true;
  }
  if (enabled) {
    $("#enablemessage").show();
    $("#message").show();
    document.getElementById("message").style.color = "green";
    document.getElementById("enablemessage").innerHTML = "Enabled";
    document.getElementById("enablemessage").style.color = "blue";
    $("#message").html("The value is correct " + limit);
  } else if (enabled == false) {
    $("#enablemessage").show();
    document.getElementById("enablemessage").innerHTML =
      "Disabled";
    document.getElementById("enablemessage").style.color = "red";
  }

}
```

Comment: If you would like to limit the seats/tickets, the usual way people deal with it is having a drop down starting from 1 and having an upper limit say 8. If your upper limit is very high, then a text field would make sense

Comment: @Andrews Maybe im not being too clear, sorry. The number limit is not exactly an issue, I need to set how many seats can be available for someone to purchase.

Comment: @gonzalo your question needs some minor changes, you don't actually ask a question at any point, just a description of what you have.

Comment: @DavidBarker my question would be what needs to be changed in order for this code to work?. Probably the if statements are not properly arranged.

Comment: Did you Write this code?

Comment: @Rob Yes, if you see any differences is only because the code was in spanish and I translated it in order to put it here.

Answer (score 0):

The function [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) returns either a number or the flag `NaN`. That means that the very first `if` never returns true. You can change it to e.g.: `if(isNaN(limit))`.

To set a fixed upper limit just test for it e.g.: `if(limit > 8)` and do something if the number in `limit` is greater than 8.